# Can "divest" mean "strip or deprive"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

Is the word *divest* used in the meaning "strip" or "deprive"? This word is in the GRE high-frequency word list, and my workbook says that it means "strip or deprive". Also, Wiktionary has [an article](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divest) with the same meaning. But I've checked a couple of dictionaries (Cambridge and Collins) and I've failed to find this meaning of the word *divest*, only "to sell something, especially business, part of business or to stop taking part in a business activity".

In which meaning is the word "divest" usually used?

Comment: @RedDwight Thank you. Not only you have improved my question, but also have given me a possibility to see my mistakes and inaccuracies through the page http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/5102/revisions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely can; the first meaning listed by [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/divest?&qsrc=) (which is identical to the definition in *Websters Encyclopedic Unabridged Dictionary* ©1983) is "to strip of clothing, ornament, etc." The sell-off-as-in-commerce definition is listed last. As you noted, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divest) doesn't give any current definition other than "to strip, deprive, or dispossess of something".

In fact, if you look at the roots, the word literally means 'remove clothing', so the usage in commerce is pretty figurative. Edit (thanks, RegDwight): [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=divest&searchmode=none) dates the economic sense only to 1955. The same site says the earliest meaning (1560s) was exactly the general "strip of possessions" that you want.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=divest&searchmode=none): 1560s, *devest* (modern spelling is c.1600), from M.Fr. *devester* "strip of possessions," from O.Fr. *desvestir*, from *des-* "away" (see *dis-*) + *vestir* "to clothe" (see *vest* (v.)). The figurative sense of "strip of possessions" is earliest in English; reflexive sense of "to strip oneself of" is from c.1600. Economic sense (implied in *divestment*) is from 1955.

Answer (score 2):

I've just checked news.google.com for the most prominent and authoritative usages of the word, and it appears that  **divest**, in most cases, implies *to strip something/someone*:

1. It also plans to divest its carbon blacks unit that is used in the rubber and tire industries
2. after agreeing to divest four psychiatric hospitals to win antitrust clearance. Psychiatric Solutions have moved on, and its stock has ceased trading....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. That's probably because my English is not good enough: I'm just learning. But in your examples isn't it used as "sell" or "stop taking part in"? Doesn't Evonik plan to sell its carbon blacks unit? Haven't Universal Services Inc. agreed to sell four psychiatric hospitals?

Comment: But Ok, I see that both meanings can be understood as a wide meaning of the word "strip" or "get rid of".

Comment: For me, "divest" is a ditransitive verb, so I would say "divest itself of its carbon black" etc. But it appears that that transitive use is becoming common.